# Disable HTML5 in WebView without disabling Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

For diagnostic purposes, I need to be able to disable HTML5 in Android's WebView, **without** disabling Javascript (i.e. keep `WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`)

To further clarify: I love the ability to play YouTube videos without any Flash plugin installed. It even works with `setPluginsEnabled(false)`.  I can do this thanks to WebView's HTML5 built-in support. Now, to **test** a certain function, I need to trigger `DownloadListener.onDownloadStart()` with a YouTube video *without* disabling Javascript.

Is this possible?

**Update**: Since I posted this question I discovered that at least [DOM storage can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858760/what-does-enable-dom-storage-api-mean). I haven't found a way to disable HTML5 video yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable HTML5"? Drop support for the new elements? Re-obscure the things the spec clarifies? ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder +1 for the clarification. "disable HTML5" in my case means disabling the ability to play YouTube videos via HTML5. I need to trigger `DownloadListener.onDownloadStart()` with such video.

Comment: Not through Webview...could you use some custom JS to modify the the page DOM elements to turn the feature off..maybe..

Comment: @Fred Grott +1 for the insight. Indeed, I combed the set*() methods in [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) but couldn't find anything that may hint at the feature I am seeking.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's very old question... Still, you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599794/2611470) for an idea. The `WebSettings` class has these methods for enabling/disabling HTML5 features:

1. [setDomStorageEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled%28boolean%29)(boolean flag) - Sets whether the DOM storage API is enabled.
2. [setDatabaseEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabaseEnabled%28boolean%29)(boolean flag) - Sets whether the database storage API is enabled.
3. [setDatabasePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)(String databasePath) - Sets the path to where database storage API databases should be saved.
4. [setAppCacheMaxSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheMaxSize%28long%29)(long appCacheMaxSize) - Note: deprecated in API 18.
5. [setAppCachePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCachePath%28java.lang.String%29)(String appCachePath) - Sets the path to the Application Caches files.
6. [setAppCacheEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheEnabled%28boolean%29)(boolean flag) - Sets whether the Application Caches API should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this question makes much sense.  You're not going to be able to "disable" an HTML5 feature in a browser that supports it.  The best you can probably do is to set a non-HTML5 doctype on the webpage, but even then most rendering engines (webkit included) will still gladly support those features (`<video>` tag, `<canvas>`, etc) that they implement.

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is test what happens with a streaming video on a particular device (with an older?.. version of webkit that doesn't support `<video>`).  Is that right?  In this case, I'm not aware of *any* version of Webkit that has ever been distributed with Android that does not have support for `<video>`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks +1 for trying to help. I explained in my original post that I need this for **diagnostic** (i.e. debug, troubelshoot) purposes. The only way I can make WebView trigger `DownloadListener.onDownloadStart()` is if I can **disable** HTML5. I have no control over the webpages through which I am trying to study my android code. So if HTML5 cannot be disabled I am basically stuck.