# What does "enable DOM storage API" mean?

Tags: android, html, dom, webview

I came across this Android WebView function `WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)` and from the name alone I can infer that it simply "enables DOM storage".

The Android documentation, however, suggests something slightly different:

> Set whether the DOM storage API is
>   enabled.

IOW, it enables the **API** rather than the storage itself.

My problem is... I didn't know about the existence of such an API until I encountered this function.

My Google search suggests that this API is closely associated with [HTML5](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/10/introduction-html5-domstorage-api-example.html).

1. Does that mean that this function is
   irrelevant to web sites/pages that
   do not use HTML5? IOW, does it
   affect existing non-HTML5 page
   loading & rendering at all?
2. <strike>Where can I learn more about the DOM
   storage API?</strike>
3. In particular, are there any gotchas
   or caveats that I need to watch for
   when calling
   `WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)`
   in an Android app?
4. Why is it disabled by default?

**Update**: I now can at least answer question #2: It turns out that the common name for "DOM Storage" is "Web Storage" and there is an entire Wikipedia article about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe this functionality is irrelevant for websites that do not use the HTML 5 specifications, since it is part of that spec. I would imagine the main thing to look out for when enabling this API is that it would then allow ANY website that takes advantage of DOM storage to use said storage options on the device. I would imagine it is disabled by default for space savings and security.

Comment: Thanks + 1 + accepting (unless a more authoritative answer comes later).

Answer (score 5):

1. No. You will have to use it to enable some features of JS functionality as well.
2. devloper.android link:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled%28boolean%29/

   MDN explnation about DOM storage:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage
3. You need to know there are security attacks that can be made  (if you use it with js).
4. It opens some security vulnerabilities of the system.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "some security vulnerabilities" claim?

Comment: I would like to understand what these  security issues are?

Comment: All the references you point to talk about vulnerabilities because of javascript and not because of enabling Dom Storage.

Comment: Downvoted for confusing Javascript vulns with enabling DOM Storage API in Android WebView.